# Looking for a media storage server

Tags: .net, cloud-storage, react

I am making a webapp using:

- ASP.NET core open api backend
- React TSX frondend
- Keycloak authentication service
- MySQL database

Now, I want to support uploading of images, and perhaps video's. (To be determined) What service could I use for this? I would like a self hosted docker image.

Comment: And what did you not like about `min.io`

Answer (score 0):

After testing with [Minio](https://min.io/), it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

BTW, I didn't know this tool when I asked this question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).